# freq histrogram by year sas9.3

Tags: sas, histogram, frequency

My dataset is the following
year | error

I would like to make an histogram with years on X, and the frequency of error (varchar) on Y.
I have tried with 
    proc freq;
   table error;
    by years;
But the outputs are three different histogram and i would only one

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Proc Univariate data=YourData;
var YourVar;
Hist;
run;
```